# How to Sort Columns in Datagrid?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to sort column in My DatagridView in Silverlight

This is My class

```
    MyGrid.CanUserSortColumns = true;
    public class Row
    {
        private Dictionary<string, object> _data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        public object this[string index]
        {
            get { return _data[index]; }
            set { _data[index] = value; }
        }
        public Dictionary<string, object> GetData()
        {
           return _data;
        }
   }
```

---

```
   ObservableCollection<Row> RowList = new ObservableCollection<Row>();

   foreach (string _Row in _DATA)
   {
       Row row = new Row();

       //some Data to add

       RowList.Add(row);
   }
}
```

---

```
PagedCollectionView RowListView = new PagedCollectionView(RowList);
this.MyGrid.ItemsSource = RowListView;
```

Still I cant Sort? What can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the  **CanUserSort="True"** for each column of your datagrid in xaml. Definitely this will work.